# Формирование SQL-запроса по указанным связям

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добрый вечер. Требуется сформировать запрос по данной таблице (например, чтобы для каждого места выводился свой уникальный объект).
Информация отображается некорректно.

```
SELECT city.id, 
place.id, 
house.id, house.title,
house.description, 
house.img_url 
FROM city, place, house
```

Comment: Добавьте в запрос условия объединения, при вашем синтаксисе (запятая) это делается в `WHERE`. просто укажите какое поле какой таблицы равно какому из другой. Без этого SQL ставит рядом с каждой строкой из первой таблица все строки из второй

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно будет некорректное отображение, потому что вы не указали поля для соединения.

У вас в каждой таблице должно быть поле для соединения с другой таблицей. Например:

```
SELECT city.id, 
   place.id, 
   house.id, house.title,
   house.description, 
   house.img_url 
FROM city, place, house
WHERE city.id = place.city_id and house.place_id = place.id
```

Без этого ваш запрос будет с [декартовым произведением](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_cartesian_product.html), где для **каждой строки** из одной таблицы будут присоединены **все строки** из другой таблицы.

---

Либо используйте [соединение таблиц `join`](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html):

```
SELECT city.id, 
   place.id, 
   house.id, house.title,
   house.description, 
   house.img_url 
FROM city
   join place on city.id = place.city_id
   join house on house.place_id = place.id
```